# hide sensitive log from keycloak quarkus distribution

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, jboss-logging

Prior to the keycloak quakus version distribution, we were hiding the ipadress & username from logs using this startup-script :

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo 
batch
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=filter-spec, value="all(substituteAll(\"(?<=ipAddress=|username=)(.*?)(?=[,\\n]|$)\",\"******\"))")
run-batch 
stop-embedded-server
```

The startup scripts are no longer supported, any idea how can I achieve it on Keycloak 18?
Maybe with adding a replace function in the log format?
The log format is passed to keycloak through the env variable `--log-console-format`, the default value is `%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n`. The ip-address and username value are coming from the `%s` (the simple log message).

Thanks